# how to configure CruiseControl for two separate builds?

Tags: cruisecontrol

I'm trying to configure CruiseControl to build the project on every modification of source code **and** every day at 3:00am. This is what I've done so far in `project.xml` (and it doesn't work, daily builds are not done):

```
...
<schedule interval="120">
  <maven2 … />
  <maven2 … time="0300"/>
</schedule>
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: CruiseControl or Cruisecontrol.NET? Please select appropriate tag

Comment: @The Chairman It is CruiseControl 2.8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand there is no possibility in CruiseControl to do this :(

Comment: We do this, and have done this for several years with CruiseControl. So it is definitely possible, please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I usally use cc.net, but when I understand the documentation correctly you have two options:

- Use 2 projects
- Set the `requireModifications` attribute to `false` (which is not exactly what you want)

What happens with your configuration is the following: The "modification" build will be run throughout the day and thus at 03:00 am CruiseControl cannot detect any modifications (at least I would assume so). As there are no modifications the daily build is not run.

From the [documentation](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#schedule):

> ... it is usually not a
>   good idea to mix time builds and
>   multiple builds in the same project as
>   the multiple builds will "eat" all the
>   changes before they can be detected by
>   the time based builds.

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I think so. Define two projects: One for the nightly build and one for the "modification" builds.

Answer (score 1):

We listen for changes in a gitrepo and do nightly builds every night, we do it like this:

```
<schedule interval="${buildtime}">
  <ant antscript="ant.bat"
   buildfile="build.xml"
  </ant>
</schedule>
<bootstrappers>
  <gitbootstrapper localWorkingCopy="${checkout_folder}"/>
</bootstrappers>
<modificationset quietperiod="${quiettime}"
         Ignorefiles="${ignorelist}">
  <git localWorkingCopy="${checkout_folder}"/>
  <timebuild username="Cruisecontrol nightwatch"
     time="0300"
     property="build_nightly"/>
</modificationset>
```

As you see here the clue here is that the timed build is placed in the `modificationset`, not the `schedule`, so at each scheduled time it will check if either the git repo has changed or the time has come to do the nightly build.

Answer (score 0):

I was using **[ScheduleTrigger](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Schedule+Trigger)** for CruiseControl.net.

Some time ago I've migrated CI server from CC.net to **[TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)** - do take a look at it (they have free version as well). It's much better and easier to configure (say goodbye to those huge unmanageable XML config files;-)

Comment: Is it possible to use this plugin with CruiseControl 2.8.3? Btw, those huge XML files are a good thing for me, since I can configure CC automatically, without any user interface.

Comment: @Vincenzo - I don't think you can use it in CC (it's in CC.net). As a side note, I also once thought that having automatic cc config files generator is a nice thing. In TeamCity you just don't need that much configuration (they have build templates, etc)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I can't migrate to CC.net (because of the platform), and I'm not ready to migrate to TeamCity. So, I'm looking for a solution for CruiseControl 2.8.3.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a way, the build script split to make plug-ins.

For example: https://github.com/LightWare/LightCI/blob/master/config.xml

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to stackoverflow. This question is old and was already answered. Typically, it is best not to resurrect stale threads unless your response contributes something significantly new or different over previous answers.